# CKEDITOR setData with HTML string returns SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, ckeditor

I am trying to display HTML Data that comes from the database into my CKEDITOR, the problem is when i try to use setData to insert the html it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

HTML:

```
<label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
<textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control descricao_anunciante" placeholder="(quem és, o que fazes ou o que representas, temas e tipos de eventos)"></textarea>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace('description', {
      customConfig: './js/wysiwygconfig.js'
    });
    CKEDITOR.instances["description"].setData("{!!  $evento->description !!}");
  });
</script>
```

but if try to insert the data mannualy it works:

```
CKEDITOR.instances["description"].setData("<p> Hello World </p>");
```

The data that is coming from the database:

```
<p>N TEM</p>
```

Comment: Are you sure, that provide correct html syntax there? [`setData`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData) requires valid html code.
Maybe you can try to assign `{!!  $evento->description !!}` to some variable and then additionally `console.log` it, to have sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace('description', {
      customConfig: './js/wysiwygconfig.js'
    });
    CKEDITOR.instances["description"].setData("{{  $evento->description }}");
  });
</script>

Or
instead of CKEDITOR.instances["description"].setData("{{  $evento->description }}"); 
you can use
<textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control descricao_anunciante" placeholder="(quem és, o que fazes ou o que representas, temas e tipos de eventos)">
   {{  $evento->description }}
</textarea>
```

This can help because "{{  }}"- this return string with htmlentities function.

Comment: Don't just post code, here, you should also include a description of your code, what's different and why it should work.

Answer (score 1):

this error is also coming to me because if you will inspect the code you can see that its giving error because the html is going into the second line so its giving syntax error you can set data only by setting the value inside textarea.

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control descricao_anunciante" placeholder="(quem és, o que fazes ou o que representas, temas e tipos de eventos)"><?= $evento->description ?></textarea>
```